# asp.net froms authentication always redirects

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication

My website should have some parts that can only be seen when the user is authenticated, some parts that are visibile to everyone.

The forms authentication always redirects the user to the login page no matter what page is visited. Does that mean I should not use forms authentication? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Change the permission (authorization). You set permission to the root folder.

Comment: Just a an interesting fact I have found out: This forms authentication also apply to your css files. You have to give anonymous permission to your css files too, using Adrians' solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <location> element in web.config to set which pages are protected. You need to remove the authorization from the whole web site set it for each protected page in the <location> element. 

A common approach is to place all protected pages in a separate folder and specify the location path to that folder. 

Another one is to have a class which inherits System.Web.Page and at the Init event to redirect the user to some page, if is not authenticated. Every page should then inherit this page.

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="public">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: When I use the inheritance method I should delete the forms authentication in web.config right?

Comment: You still need to remove the authorization policy from the root and you still need to use authentication mode as forms, it helps you to access and use HttpContext.Curent.User. If you are having few pages to protect I recommend you to go the &lt;location&gt; way

Comment: Actually my situation is vice versa. I hava a few pages not to protect. Would <location> help in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the `MachineKey`.  It's required to decrypt/encrypt the cookie *if* you are doing that (for example: a web farm).  Because the app couldn't decrypt the cookie, even though it was getting passed back and forth, the app acted like the cookie wasn't even there.  Adding this setting to web.config fixed it for me:

```
<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" validationKey="some_hard_coded_long_key" decryptionKey="another_hard_coded_long_key" validation="SHA1" />
```

See this article for more on the [machinekey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx).